# cannot run async function inside express, how to fix?

Tags: javascript, express

Async function not run inside express view, console log, before and after function, separately code working, but with express it doesn't.

```
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express()
const port = 9596;
app.use(bodyParser.json());
  
app.post('/', async function(req, res){
    siteName = req.body.siteName;
    links = req.body.links;
    screenshotPageSource = req.body.screenshotPageSource;

    await createScreenshots(siteName, links, screenshotPageSource);
    
    res.end('Hello World!');
});
  
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
  })


async function createScreenshots(siteName, links, screenshotPageSource){

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({defaultViewport: { width: 1366, height: 768 }});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    linksLength = links.Length;

    for (var i = 0; i < linksLength; i++) {
        link = links[i]
        if(screenshotPageSource){
            currentLink = `view-source:${link}`;
        } else {
            currentLink = link;
        }
    
        pageNumber = i + 1;
        
        console.log(pageNumber);

        await page.goto(currentLink, {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 60000}).then(() => {
            console.log(`Страница ${pageNumber}/${linksLength}, удалось сделать скриншот.`)
        }).catch((res) => {
            console.log(`Страница ${pageNumber}/${linksLength}, не удалось сделать скриншот.`)
        });
        await page.screenshot({ path: `${siteName}__${pageNumber}.png` });
    }
    
    await browser.close();
    return links;
};
```

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: One issue is you need to close the connection. Call `res.end()` after `res.send()` or replace `res.send()` with `res.end('Hello World')`.

Comment: @slebetman I replaced it, but still function not run, I cannot see my output which i set in there, can you help me pls?

Answer (score 0):

The problem I guess is in `app.post`.

Below is have added a code for your reference which might help you to edit your code.

```
app.post('/', async(req, res, next) => { 
    const { error } = validateBody(req.body);

    if (error) {
        return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
    }    
    const newData= new createScreenshots({ 
    siteName = req.body.siteName;
    links = req.body.links;
    screenshotPageSource = req.body.screenshotPageSource; });    


await newData.save();
    console.log('saving the document');
    res.send(newData);
})
```

The above code is just for your reference as to how you can write `app.post()`